# show cart Grandtotal

Tags: magento-1.9

In My website i want to show in this way

**Grand total = subtotal + tax**

[image]

[image]

Even i can't under stand how it will display and how taking tax based on product. Can you please explain some one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got answer in my question

In Shopping cart page want to show subtotal without tax then go to

```
/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/tax/checkout
```

Find this

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->getTotal()->getValue(), false, false);
```

and change into

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

No need to set **Exclude tax**

Answer (score 1):

Go admin side system -> Configuration -> Tax (under left side Sales) and set bellow settings

[image]
Configure taxable product in admin side

[image]

And show fronted Side:

[image]

Comment: i want to display grand total =  152.3 (142.95 + 9.35 )

Comment: But your qusestion Grand Total Display included tax (2400)

Comment: check my question i mention in 1st line Grand total = subtotal + tax

Comment: are you display product price included with tax?

Comment: Abdul@ update answer please check.